Fetch entity relations using native sql query in JPA repository method
I have a repository method to fetch EmailSubscriptions
    @Query("SELECT es FROM EmailSubscription es "
        + "JOIN FETCH es.subscriber s "
        + "WHERE es.id > :batchStartId "
        + "AND es.subscriptionTypeId = :typeId "
        + "AND es.active = :active "
        + "ORDER BY es.id ASC")
    List<EmailSubscription> findByIdGreaterThanAndSubscriptionTypeIdAndActive(
        @Param("batchStartId") long batchStartId,
        @Param("typeId") Integer typeId,
        @Param("active") Boolean active,
        Pageable pageable);

Here is how EmailSubscriptions is defined.
public class EmailSubscription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type_id")
    private Integer subscriptionTypeId;
    private Boolean active;
    @Pattern(regexp = LOCALE_VALIDATION_REGEX, message = "invalid code")
    private String locale;
    private LocalDateTime lastSentTimestamp;
    private Integer lastSentSequence;
    private Long lastUpdatePersonId;
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateTimestamp;
    private LocalDateTime creationTimestamp;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Subscriber.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subscriber subscriber;
}

Unfortunately this query is very expensive for a batch of 10k records (10+ seconds).
So I wrote a native sql query which is under 1 second to fetch 10k records.
            @Query(value = "SELECT es.* FROM subscriptions.email_subscriptions es "
                + "IGNORE INDEX (PRIMARY) "
                + "JOIN subscriptions.subscribers s ON es.subscriber_id = s.id "
                + "WHERE es.type_id = :typeId "
                + "AND es.active = :active "
                + "AND es.id > :batchStartId "
                + "ORDER BY es.id ", nativeQuery = true)

But unfortunately this query only fetches EmailSubscriptions without its Subscriber relation. How can I fetch Subscriber within EmailSusbcription using native sql query

You don't as you probably end up with the same query as Hibernate and have to do the mapping yourself. What you should do is consider ifyou really need those 10k records all in one or you can receive and process them streaming. Also set the fetch size to something other then the default (which is 10) to reduce the roundtrips. You can use a query hint for that (for use with the JPA query).

Instead of working around JPA and the features it gives, embrace it. Also understand JDBC and the default settings.
In this case you need to understand fetch sizes. Most JDBC drivers have a fetch size of 10. Which means it will retrieve 10 rows, process them and retrieve the next 10. Each call is IO/network access which is slow.
Increase the fetchsize for this query, you can use an @QueryHint with Spring Data for that.
@Query("SELECT es FROM com.cargurus.emailsubscriptions.entity.EmailSubscription es "
        + "JOIN FETCH es.subscriber s "
        + "WHERE es.id > :batchStartId "
        + "AND es.subscriptionTypeId = :typeId "
        + "AND es.active = :active "
        + "ORDER BY es.id ASC")
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = "1000"))
List<EmailSubscription> findByIdGreaterThanAndSubscriptionTypeIdAndActive(
        @Param("batchStartId") long batchStartId,
        @Param("typeId") Integer typeId,
        @Param("active") Boolean active,
        Pageable pageable);

Rewriting this with SQL won't help as you probably endup with the same query that Hibernate generates but you will have to do the mapping yourself (leading to the same slowness).

Thank you. Query hint change totally worked

Try this.
@Query(value = "SELECT es.id as es_id, es.type_id as es_type_id, es.active as es_active, es.locale as es_locale, " +
               "es.last_sent_timestamp as es_last_sent_timestamp, es.last_sent_sequence as es_last_sent_sequence, " +
               "es.last_update_person_id as es_last_update_person_id, es.last_update_timestamp as es_last_update_timestamp, " +
               "es.creation_timestamp as es_creation_timestamp, " +
               "s.id as s_id, s.name as s_name, s.email as s_email " + // select subscriber fields
               "FROM subscriptions.email_subscriptions es " +
               "JOIN subscriptions.subscribers s ON es.subscriber_id = s.id " +
               "WHERE es.type_id = :typeId " +
               "AND es.active = :active " +
               "AND es.id > :batchStartId " +
               "ORDER BY es.id ",
       nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findByIdGreaterThanAndSubscriptionTypeIdAndActiveWithSubscriber(
    @Param("batchStartId") long batchStartId,
    @Param("typeId") Integer typeId,
    @Param("active") Boolean active);

Since you're fetching a native query result in an List<Object[]>, you can manually map the results to your entities.
